# How do I publish gazebo position of a robot model on odometry topic

Tags: gazebo, navigation, odometry, state, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have a robot model that runs using teleop key, and I want to publish its position and velocity on odometry topic. How should I achieve this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222033/how-do-i-publish-gazebo-position-of-a-robot-model-on-odometry-topic./) by [cybodroid](https://answers.ros.org/users/25023/cybodroid/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2015-12-06

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the [gazebo_ros_p3d](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_plugins/include/gazebo_plugins/gazebo_ros_p3d.h) plugin in your robot's URDF to directly publish (ground truth) odometry for your robot. Here's a usage example: [tracker_chassis.gazebo.xacro.xml](https://github.com/tu-darmstadt-ros-pkg/taurob_tracker_common/blob/master/taurob_tracker_description/urdf/tracker_chassis.gazebo.xacro.xml#L44)

For your use case (publishing directly to `odom`) it would probably look like this:

```
<plugin name="p3d_base_controller" filename="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
  <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
  <updateRate>50.0</updateRate>
  <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
  <topicName>odom</topicName>
  <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
  <frameName>world</frameName>
  <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets>
  <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
</plugin>
```

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2017-10-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 12

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ankita](https://answers.ros.org/users/54326/ankita/) on 2021-07-24**:
Thanks, it worked for me. Now, I am able to get position data of my robot from the gazebo. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can do that by doing two options:

1. You compute the odometry based on the movement of the robot and odometry equations
2. You get the odometry directly asking Gazebo how much your robot moved

Once you have that data, you create a topic with Odometry msg type and publish the data obtained from the call.

Since you are not providing any information about your robot, we cannot explain here option 1. Let's explain option 2

In order to get how much the robot moved you should call the `/gazebo/get_model_state` service provided by Gazebo. That service will provide you with the current position of the robot in the world. In order to call it, do the following:

```
rosservice call /gazebo/get_model_state "model_name: 'the_name_of_your_robot' relative_entity_name: ' ' "
```

Just calling that service you will get the current position of the robot in Gazebo. However, you must do that call inside a node to get the position data and publish it later in an odometry topic. You can do all that with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from nav_msgs.msg import Odometry
from std_msgs.msg import Header
from gazebo_msgs.srv import GetModelState, GetModelStateRequest

rospy.init_node('odom_pub')

odom_pub=rospy.Publisher ('/my_odom', odometry)

rospy.wait_for_service ('/gazebo/get_model_state')
get_model_srv = rospy.ServiceProxy('/gazebo/get_model_state', GetModelstate)

odom=Odometry()
header = Header()
header.frame_id='/odom'

model = GetModelStateRequest()
model.model_name='the_name_of_your_robot'

r = rospy.Rate(2)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    result = get_model_srv(model)

    odom.pose.pose = result.pose
    odom.twist.twist = result.twist

    header.stamp = rospy.Time.now()
    odom.header = header

    odom_pub.publish (odom)

    r.sleep()
```

That's it! That Python code will do exactly that: get the robot position from the simulator, and then publish it in an odometry topic.

Here you can find a video (https://youtu.be/I_5leJK8vhQ) that shows how to do all the explained above with a full example for a kobuki robot.

---

Originally posted by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) with karma: 874 on 2017-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-07-26**:
This answer would be greatly improved by adding the instructions given in the video. Links can and do change/go down, and if this were to happen then this accepted answer would no longer useful.

**Comment by [R. Tellez](https://answers.ros.org/users/22719/r.-tellez/) on 2017-10-09**:
Answer edited and corrected as requested. Cheers